# How to choose right context

Tags: python, workspaces

I would like to fit in the image in Texture Paint WORKSPACE, but I still got the same error `RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.image.view_all.poll() failed, context is incorrect`. -> I do not understand how it is possible because before this part I wrote `bpy.context.window.workspace = bpy.data.workspaces["Texture Paint"]`. Could someone help me with the context. I thought that the `bpy.ops.image.view_all(fit_view=True)` is for Texture Paint context (I am maybe a bit confused about what is WORKSPACE and what is context). Thank you :)

Comment: So you want to downsize the image as in reduce it's resolution or just make it smaller so it can be seen in the viewport?

Comment: @Jakemoyo I edited the question and now should be more clear.

Comment: Try looking into [this sort of thing](https://b3d.interplanety.org/en/context-override/) except you will want to use [context.temp_override()](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Context.html#bpy.types.Context.temp_override) instead of create a context dictionary. That is a recent update to the API post 3.0 IIRC. The procedure is essentially the same though.

Comment: I maybe don't get it, but what is the purpose of overriding the context, and what is the difference between the workspace and context? :O Because I thought that all I need to do is to change the workspace and work with that.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/270716/142292

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `bpy.ops.image.view_all` your context needs to be within the `IMAGE_EDITOR`. [Read more about context here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

```
import bpy

area_type = 'IMAGE_EDITOR' # change this to use the correct Area Type context you want to process in
areas  = [area for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas if area.type == area_type]

if len(areas) <= 0:
    raise Exception(f"Make sure an Area of type {area_type} is open or visible in your screen!")

override = {
    'window': bpy.context.window,
    'screen': bpy.context.window.screen,
    'area': areas[0],
    'region': [region for region in areas[0].regions if region.type == 'WINDOW'][0],
}

bpy.ops.image.view_all(override, fit_view=True)
```